# Visa VS airline

Tags: air-travel, airlines, disputes

I have one situation. I have visa for the country I  want to visit and airline refuse me for boarding because they said they don't believe my visa. And my flights (including travel plan) are ruined. What can I do to that airline? Please suggest me. Thanks. My citizenship is Myanmar. Visa is visit visa to Jamaica. There is No Jamaica embassy in Myanmar. And I get the visa applied by my son who live in Jamaica and visa was stamped by British Embassy in Bangkok. Vietnam airline said they never see the visa stamped by embassy from other country. They asked why UK embassy in Bangkok issued visa and why not by UK embassy in Yangon. But UK embassy in Yangon ( that is my country capital) don't issue the Jamaica visa. Travel plan is Yangon to Vietnam to Frankfurt to Jamaica. No visa needed for both Vietnam and Germany for transit.

Comment: Where did this happen? And did you use a travel agent to arrange and acquire your visa?

Comment: What country, what airline, what is your citizenship?  The airline has the responsibility to make sure you have proper documentation to enter the destination.  If they feel your visa looks fake, it is their duty to deny boarding.

Comment: We need to know your citizenship, and where you were going to (and from).

Answer (score 1):

If it's really the airline's mistake, and you meet the officially published entry requirements for that country, as well as any written requirements regarding entry to that country on the airline's website (if any), you can sue the airline for the damages you suffered because of not being able to go on the flight. However, depending on your situation, a lawsuit may be more hassle than it's worth.